# How to configure TextWrapping for CheckBox control?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I need to set TextWrapping for CheckBox like for TextBlock, but CheckBox hasn't TextWrapping property. How to configure TextWrapping for CheckBox?

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.CleanCity, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="32" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="c1" Foreground="{StaticResource CustomApplicationTextBrush}" Background="#BFC2E2FD"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="c2" Foreground="{StaticResource CustomApplicationTextBrush}" Background="#BFC2E2FD"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="c3" Foreground="{StaticResource CustomApplicationTextBrush}" Background="#BFC2E2FD"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="c4" Foreground="{StaticResource CustomApplicationTextBrush}" Background="#BFC2E2FD"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="c5" Foreground="{StaticResource CustomApplicationTextBrush}" Background="#BFC2E2FD"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.SafeCity, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="32" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="c6" Foreground="{StaticResource CustomApplicationTextBrush}" Background="#BFC2E2FD"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.ComfortableCity, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="32" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="c7" Foreground="{StaticResource CustomApplicationTextBrush}" Background="#BFC2E2FD"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="c8" Foreground="{StaticResource CustomApplicationTextBrush}" Background="#BFC2E2FD"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="c9" Foreground="{StaticResource CustomApplicationTextBrush}" Background="#BFC2E2FD"/>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you share your code, so that we can help you..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkbox can be declared like this as well

```
        <CheckBox>
            <TextBlock>
                Hi
            </TextBlock>
        </CheckBox>
```

Now textblock supports textwrapping :)

Edits

```
           <CheckBox>
            <CheckBox.Content>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="100">
                Hi fkffk kffk f fkfkf fk kfhkf fkf kf fkfk
            </TextBlock>
            </CheckBox.Content>
          </CheckBox>
```

the above edit would enable checking unchecking on tapping the textblock.

to set the text from code behind

```
(yourcheckbox.Content as Textblock).Text="Hi world!";
```

Comment: You have to add width here either in TextBlock or in Checkbox. In XAML, it will take width="Auto" and never wrap your control if you haven't assigned width property to your control.

Comment: yes.. I am assuming that the splash27 is able to put a textwrapping and width on textblock. That is There is no need to mention that'.

Comment: I set the Content property from code-behind, it overrides the markup with inner TextBlock. Unfortunately, this is not a solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can always add textblock inside checkbox like this.

```
<CheckBox>
    <TextBlock Width="250" TextWrapping="Wrap">
               Write your text here and wrap it whenever you want..!!
    </TextBlock>
</CheckBox>
```

Note : This will not allow you to check/uncheck box when you click on text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float: left;` in your css file

You can refer this JSfiddle Link (http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9s8Db/10/) . this will help you for sure..!